# c# casting across different assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, casting, assemblies

I am working as a part of a large project. The company that I work for decided to shift some of its code into a webservice for some efficiency and code consolidation reasons. I have converted some code to stop using references to other assemblies inside the project. Now the code now uses the code generated when I added the web reference to the project.

The problem is that the components that use the code that I modified supply objects constructed from different assemblies whereas I create/use/return objects from the generated code. Now even though the objects are identical i cant cast them to each other. Is there any way to force a cast as the objects I am concerned with are very bulky and I dont want to write a custom mapper or something of that sort.

An example of the problem is : the project contains many small components A,B,C...Z

The code used objects of class in component A caled lets say apple eg A,apple()

now after the change the code uses objects created using the auto generated webservice class called "Web" so Web.apple()

The webservice in the back actually references A.apple anyways so Web.Apple and A.apple are the same thing.

So how do I make c# believe me that they are indeed the same thing and stop giving me casting errors?

P.S in accordance with company policy I cant upload any code but I think that is irrelevant since the example ablove should explain the situation.

And thanks in advance

Thanks a lot for your answers and this is what I did in the end :

I discovered that Apple has a merge method and I merged Web.apple and A.apple together.. 
I guess some one before me had gone through the trouble of solving this issue..

Once again thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a service reference you can reuse Objects so that they are not built again (of course, you'll lose the nifty auto-generated stuff).

For example:

SERVER:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://abc.com/"]
public class Apple
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsEvil { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public bool IsPoisoned { get; set; }
}
```

CLIENT:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://abc.com/"]
public class Apple
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsEvil { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public bool ClientSideBool { get; set; }
}
```

These two match up in name and namespace and the datamembers match up. If the app/assembly that contains the service reference has a reference to this object it will NOT recode it. Instead, it will reuse it. Of course, everything has to match up including the XML namespace, name, datamember requirements, order, name, etc. You're external assembly that contains `Apple` will have to be compiled and referenced before adding a service reference (or you'll have to referesh the service reference).

A nice way to ensure that the namespace matches is to use the `ContractNamespaceAttribute` which maps your CLR namespace to an XML namespace. Make sure that both objects map to the same XML namespace.

Comment: thanks I will try to match evety thing up

Answer (score 2):

I think [`AutoMapper`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your time but unfortunately the company does not allow me to *technically* install unauthorized softwares so I was hoping more for a hack to achieve this in c# itself.. If i cant figure anything out I will definately give this a try.. Once again thanks

Comment: You don't need to install anything. Just download the DLL and reference it in your project or download the C# files and directly include them into your project.

Answer (score 1):

When you import a web service reference into any other application, .NET creates client proxies on your behalf. They may *appear* to be identical, but they are in fact entirely different types. This is where you'll see people create **data transfer obejcts** (DTOs) simply to perform mapping.

As @Daniel Hilgarth suggested, you will probably want to use AutoMapper. It uses rules to automate a lot of the tedious nature in creating DTOs.